# Strange behavior of typing a vector

Tags: input

When I input a complex 4-component vector, the mathematica throws an error:
[image]

After then, I obtained the InputForm of the errorneous result as follows:

```
{(E^(I*\[Phi])*(px^2 + py^2 - Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]*\[Mu]) + E^(I*\[Phi])*Sqrt[(px^2 + py^2)*(px^2 + py^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 2*Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]*\[Mu] + \[Mu]^2)])/((px + I*py)*\[CapitalDelta]), 
 (E^(I*\[Phi])*(Sqrt[px^2 + py^2] - \[Mu]) + E^(I*\[Phi])*Sqrt[px^2 + py^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2 - 2*Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]*\[Mu] + \[Mu]^2])/\[CapitalDelta], Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]/(px + I*py), 1}
```

After I re-type this InputForm result, then there is no error and the exact same expression is recovered!
What happened in this process, and why there was an error in the first try?

Comment: i suspect it could be a bug. Mathematica  sometimes gets 'confused' when you use multiple ratios, square roots etc... I've personally noticed it when dealing with functions that if there is an error, just simplify the expression and it works.